# Is Bailey voiced by Colonel Tigh?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Every time I talk to him I keep picturing him w/ an eye-patch. I'm quite a way from the end and would like to know now rather than have to wait until I beat the game.

Is it the same actor?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Some people in the community just don't like trivia questions, unfortunately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, you've got a good ear.

[Michael Hogan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Hogan_%28Canadian_actor%29) is Captain Bailey's voice actor, as well as your friend from Battlestar Galactica.